# Adding Books x Category PHP

Tags: php, class, oop

Basically I need to create a method addLibrosXCategoria(Libreria, codCategoria), which means addBooksXCategory(Libery, codCategory). I've created my Books class, and my Category class and filled it up with the books I made up. So basically what I need is in the Category class to fill up the atribute listaLibros with the ones I've created under dbListaLibros (dbBooksList pretty much). How would I go about this? Basically saving book per category under attribute listaLibros (booksList)

So I got my class Books and Categories (Libros and Categoria in spanish)

CLASS BOOKS

```
class Libro {

var $codigo;
var $categoria;
var $titulo;
var $autor;
var $editorial;
var $imagen;

public function __construct($cod, $cat, $tit, $aut, $edi, $ima) {
    $this->codigo = $cod;
    $this->categoria = $cat;
    $this->titulo = $tit;
    $this->autor = $aut;
    $this->editorial = $edi;
    $this->imagen = $ima;
}

function getCodigo() {
    return $this->codigo;
}

function getCategoria() {
    return $this->categoria;
}

function getTitulo() {
    return $this->titulo;
}

function getAutor() {
    return $this->autor;
}

function getEditorial() {
    return $this->editorial;
}

function getImagen() {
    return $this->imagen;
}
}
```

CLASS CATEGORY

```
class Categoria {

var $nombre;
var $codigo;
var $listaLibros;

public function __construct($nom, $cod) {
    $this->nombre = $nom;
    $this->codigo = $cod;
}

function getNombre() {
    return $this->nombre;
}

function getCodigo() {
    return $this->codigo;
}
}
```

LIST OF BOOKS

```
 <?php

require 'clases/Libro.php';

class dbListaLibros {
    var $db;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->db = array();

        $libro1 = new Libro(00001, "Cocina", "Comiendo", "Juancito", "Test", "../images/image_01.jpg");
        $libro2 = new Libro(00002, "Computacion", "Programacion", "Maria", "test", "../images/image_01.jpg");
        $libro3 = new Libro(00003, "Redes", "Cisco", "Ramon", "test","../images/image_01.jpg");
        $libro4 = new Libro(00004, "Electronica", "Circuitos", "Jose", "test","../images/image_01.jpg");

        array_push($this->db, $libro1, $libro2, $libro3, $libro4);
    }

    function getLibros() {

        echo"<table border=1>";
        echo"<tr>";
             echo"<td>Codigo</td>";
             echo"<td>Categoria</td>";
             echo"<td>Nombre</td>";
             echo"<td>Autor</td>";
             echo"<td>Editorial</td>";
             echo"<td>Imagen</td>";
        echo"</tr>";

        foreach ($this->db as $libros) {
            echo"<tr>";
            foreach ($libros as $valor) {
                echo"<td>$valor <br/></td>";
            }
            echo"</tr>";

        }

        echo"</table>";
        echo"<ul>";
    }
}
```

LIST OF CATEGORIES

```
require 'clases/Categoria.php';

class dbCategorias {
    var $db;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->db = array();

        $cate1 = new Categoria("FO001", "Fotografía");
        $cate2 = new Categoria("CO001", "Cocina");
        $cate3 = new Categoria("JA001", "Jardinería");
        $cate4 = new Categoria("NO001", "Novelas");
        $cate5 = new Categoria("HI001", "Historia");
        $cate6 = new Categoria("CI001", "Ciencia");
        $cate7 = new Categoria("TE001", "Tecnología");

        array_push($this->db, $cate1, $cate2, $cate3, $cate4, $cate5, $cate6, $cate7);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be done in your controller logic (or script that receives user input). You could add a property "libros" to your Category class which would be an array of Book objects. Then you could add the following methods to your category class:

```
function getBooks() {
    return $this->libros;
}

function addBook(Libro $libro) {
    $this->libros[] = $libro;
}
```

I would recommend researching the Data Mapper pattern for addressing a long-term solution for your application. Google "PHP Mapper Pattern" should return plenty of examples.